# selenium: is selenium a RESTful service?

Tags: selenium

is selenium test framework a REST service? i'm not asking if selenium can be used to test REST services, but if the framework itself is REST architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the WebDriver commands work through `JSON` wire protocol via http and defines as RESTful service. So, yes they are RESTful serives. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#Introduction)

Comment: @lilredindy See [this](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#Commands)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a library, but not a framework. As it was already said, it uses wire protocol to send commands to browser by generating jsons